# How to create Unit Tests for Xamarin / Bitrise

Tags: xamarin, continuous-integration, bitrise

I'm setting up a new Hybrid Mobile Application with Xamarin and I want to use Bitrise for the Continuous Integration. But I don't know how to properly create tests.

Right now, I've setup a Workflow where I build the project, in order to run tests I read that I need to use the NUnit Runner step (which I added) but I don't know where I should put my tests in my projects for this step to execute them.

I tried to add a new NUnit Project with Visual Studio in my solution
My test look like this :

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
}
```

So it should execute withput any problem right ? But when my Workflow is executed I end up with an error like this one: `Failed to read test result, error: test result not exist at: /Users/vagrant/deploy/TestResult.xml`

I've got all the default settings for the NUnit step in my Workflow.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple unit testing frameworks, NUnit, XUnit & Microsoft Testing Framework.
According to some documents, Bitrise is able to support two of them: [NUnit](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/getting-started/getting-started-with-xamarin-apps/) & [XUnit](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/add-unittest-to-your-xamarin-app/93).

So when I tried to Add a new Unit Test project to my Xamarin solution, I chose NUnit and in the Toolbar clicked Build->Rebuild UnitTests.

Then I selected View->Debug Pads-> Unit Tests and then Run All.
You ll see that the default test will run & a test results box will appear saying all the tests pass.